# Laravel https route for form

Tags: php, https, laravel

Is there way to submit a form over https using the blade syntax?

I have `{{Form::open(['route' => 'pages.store', 'class' => 'crud-form'])}}` but this uses http://

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing your route to be secure

`Route::post('page/store', array('https', 'as' => 'pages.store');`

Answer (score 2):

Securing routes didn't do the trick for me. Instead i added the following to my `AppServiceProvider` in the `boot()` method:

```
// forces use of https instead of http

URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Answer (score 1):

a better way would be securing the route it self rather than the form, maybe something like that

```
Route::post('/pages', [
    'https' => true
    'as'    => 'pages.store'
    'uses'  => 'PagesController@store''
]);
```

or

```
Route::group(['https'], function()
{
    // ur routes
});
```

check http://laravel.io/forum/12-26-2014-routing-with-https & https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/578 for more info.